# get element by tag name [this]?

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, getelementsbytagname

First a short background. So I just started practicing using API's. With the one I'm working with right now, I'm loading a DIV which have alot of links in it which I have to give a new purpose. I managed to prevent the default onclick-function. Now I need do save the clicked link "innerHTML" attribute.

```
var nextPage = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[this].innerHTML;
```

with [this] I tried to target the clicked link, but it didn't work. Hopefully you understands what I'm trying to do. If so, is there any way I an solve this problem?

Thanks!

EDIT:

```
     $("#content, a").click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();

     var x = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0].innerHTML;
    console.log(x)



 getPage(x);
 });
```

Comment: You were close, need to pass a number in as `index` in `[index]` test with `0`

Comment: Yes, I know. For example if I write [0] I will target the first link. But there are multiple links with diffrent innerHTML-attributes and I only want to save the clicked one's innerHTML.

Comment: Yes I agree with @ZakariaAcharki. Have you tried `this.innerHTML` ?

Comment: Show us the click listener so we know what `this` is and can help you further

Comment: @Surya Purohit That would give me the entire html-page.

Comment: @Mawcel You can now see the code

Comment: var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');

for (let x of links) {
  x.onclick = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.innerHTML);
  }
}

Try this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add an `onclick` listener to all the `a` tags elements

```js
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
for (var i = 0, il = links.length; i < il; i++) {
  links[i].onclick = clickHandler;
}

function clickHandler(event) {
  console.log(this.innerHTML);
}
```

```html
<a>Link a</a>
<a>Link b</a>
```

Comment: Why to use a loop to bind a click to anchor???? If jquery can be used, loop should not be used.

Comment: @SuryaPurohit That's true. I just went to a full JS answer. No need to be rude

Answer (score 4):

first the `document.getElementsByTagName("a")[this].innerHTML;` will return `undefined` because it will return a collection of html node and it must pass index not the `this`.

Since you already have a click you can try this code :

```
function yourClickFunction(event) {
  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  var nextPage = target.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: This also work! But I have trouble understanding this line "  var target = event.target || event.srcElement;
  var nextPage = target.innerHTML; ". Would you mind explaining?

Comment: That means, get the element that triggered event and store it in target variable

Answer (score 3):

Use jQuery for this:

```
$('a').on('click', function(){
  // this will run with every click, and 'this' will be your clicked item
  console.log(this.innerHTML);

  // although you probably want:
  console.log($(this).attr('href'));
});
```

Using jQuery makes your code much cleaner, and unifying the cross browsers compatibility issues you might have when handling directly with the DOM api.

Comment: Yes, I'm using jquery when loading the API, I have also tried to fix my problem with jquery but didn't manage. I did try the secound console.log. but this gave me undefined.

Comment: Did you bind the 'click' event same way as in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

`this.innerHTML` can do the work, if I am getting you correctly.

If you are getting the entire html in it, you can bind an onclick event to the anchor itself and can work on that if that is possible.

```
<a onclick="clicked(this)">Click me</a>
function clicked(element) {
    // Do whatever needed
    // element.innerHTML will change it's innerHTML
}
```

You can it like the following too

```
$("#content, a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    event.target.innerHTML = "Whatever";
})
```

Comment: I don't know if i can do that since the HTML-page is loaded by the API.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a common class (`link` in the below example) to attach the click event then just use `this.innerHTML` to return the text of you clicked link.

Hope this helps.

```js
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("link");

var clickFunction = function(){
  //Prevent default
  if ( event.preventDefault ) event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = false;
  
  //Get text
  console.log(this.innerHTML);
}

for(var i=0;i<classname.length;i++){
  classname[i].addEventListener('click', clickFunction, false);
}
```

```html
<a href='link-1' class='link'>Link 1</a>
<a href='link-2' class='link'>Link 2</a>
<a href='link-3' class='link'>Link 3</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName("a")` gives you an array of HTMLAnchorElement. The indexes of the array are integer values from 0 to n.

`this` in your context i think it's the `windows` object (your code example is a bit short so i have to guess a bit)

using `window` as the index for the array that expects an integer of course gives you nothing. or `undefined` to be precise.

There're two possible ways to do what you're looking for:

### onclick handler

```js
function hello(elem) {
  console.log("you clicked on '" + elem.innerHTML + "'")
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="hello(this)">click me</a>
```

Here i'm using the onclick property and I pass the `this` context from the html as an argument to the function i'm calling. This is important.
Now i can operate on the element that was clicked just by referencing the argument received.

I would not suggest this method for a number or reasons. But since you mention the onclick property in the question ...

### click event handler

this would be my preferred solution

```js
function hello(evt) {
  var elem = event.target || event.srcElement;
  console.log("you clicked on '" + elem.innerHTML + "'");
}

var link = document.getElementsByTagName("a")[0]
link.addEventListener("click", hello)
```

```html
<a href="#">click me</a>
```

Here there's no code (or reference to the code) in the html. You instead retrieve the HTMLAnchorElement from the code and attach a listener to the `click` event.
Now the event handler will be called whenever the link is clicked and it will receive an event object by default. From that object you can extract the `target` (the object that generated the event) and access its properties.